# Crosstab/Pivot query in TSQL on nvarchar columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, pivot, dynamic-pivot

I have a Table1:

```
ID  Property
1   Name
2   City
3   Designation
```

and Table2:

```
ID  RecordID  Table1ID  Value
1   1         1         David
2   1         2         Tokyo
3   2         1         Scott
4   2         3         Manager
```

The Table1ID of Table2 maps to Table1's ID. Now I wish to show the Table1 Property column values as column headers and have a result set in format like:

```
RecordID     Name    City    Designation
1            David   Tokyo   NULL
2            Scott   NULL    Manager
```

What is the best/efficient way to achieve this in T-SQL **considering that the number of records in Table1 (i.e. the columns in result set) can change and thus should be handled dynamically**.

Although I tried PIVOT and CASE based queries, but have been struggling with both of them. :(

Any help/guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks!

**Update:**
I've been able to create the dynamic query, but one thing which I am still not able to understand is why MAX has been used in the CASE statements. Kindly ignore my noobness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT t2.recordid,
         MAX(CASE WHEN t1.property = 'Name' THEN t2.value END) AS name,
         MAX(CASE WHEN t1.property = 'City' THEN t2.value END) AS city,
         MAX(CASE WHEN t1.property = 'Designation' THEN t2.value END) AS designation
    FROM TABLE2 t2
    JOIN TABLE1 t1 ON t1.id = t2.table1id
GROUP BY t2.recordid
ORDER BY t2.recordid
```

Comment: ^^ Great! just two questions: 1. Why did you use the aggregate fn. 
MAX for every CASE?

2. How to handle the CASE statements dynamically when number of entries in t1.Property can change? Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: +1 - for this sort of issue, this is preferably to PIVOT in my mind - I'll never remember the syntax for PIVOT.  :)